# When i Update my existing data System.Reflection.TargetException ERROR

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am using web api to insert update read delete data from database using angularjs ajax but when i update my data i get error.

My WEB API code for Update:

```
    [Route("api/UpdateAdmin")]
    [HttpPost]
    public bool UpdateAdmin(Admin admin)
    {
        using (FirstdbEntities ent = new FirstdbEntities())
        {
            Admin updatedAdmin = (from c in ent.Admins where c.Name == admin.Name select 
 c).FirstOrDefault();   //here i get the error System.Reflection.TargetException.
            updatedAdmin.City = admin.City;
            updatedAdmin.Role = admin.Role;
            ent.SaveChanges();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

my angularjs code that is implemented on click of button:

```
   $scope.Update = function (x) {
            var admin = $scope.adminlist[x];
            var httprequest = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: "api/UpdateAdmin/",
                data: JSON.stringify(admin),
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            })
            .then(function (data) {
                alert('Data Updated successfully.');
                $scope.adminlist.push(data.data);
            });
        }
```

my button:

```
<input type="button" class="bg-danger" value="Update" ng-click="Update(ax)" />
```

Kindly advice me what to do.Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can't send `admin` parameter to server correctly. Thus `admin` parameter is always null in your `UpdateAdmin` method. You need to change usage of [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

So this

```
 data: JSON.stringify(admin)
```

should be as below in AJAX call:

```
data: JSON.stringify({admin: admin})
```

And this is not about the problem but, I would add null check too:

```
using (FirstdbEntities ent = new FirstdbEntities())
{
    Admin updatedAdmin = ent.Admins.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Name == admin.Name);
    if(updatedAdmin != null)
    {
        updatedAdmin.City = admin.City;
        updatedAdmin.Role = admin.Role;
        ent.SaveChanges();
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: after changing the code it give another error :System.NullReferenceException in web-api

Comment: Could you please put debugger on entrance of `UpdateAdmin` method and check `admin` is null.

Comment: So your problem is  `var admin = $scope.adminlist[x];`, make sure that you have admin data.